# Generate unique and unpredictable path for photos in s3

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I want to use s3 public bucket to store photos. But if I will name photo paths like *${userId}...*. then I think that other users will be able to easily brute-force such URLs and load photos for other users. Are there any approaches how to avoid that? I suppose I need to randomize URLs somehow.. how facebook or other social networks do that?

Comment: SHA-256 payload hash, perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your requirement correctly but [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html) might be the direction for you.

Since by default all objects are private, basically you generate a pre-signed URL and share with the intended users for them to download the objects within the time

> All objects by default are private. Only the object owner has permission to access these objects. However, the object owner can optionally share objects with others by creating a pre-signed URL, using their own security credentials, to grant time-limited permission to download the objects.

If you only want to know what's the best practices for S3 naming convention, you can refer to [this](http://blog.gyanmatrix.com/s3-best-practices/) to have a full picture of it. In shorts, you can try to create the name as random as possible, perhaps the name starts with **ss-mm-hh-FileName** ?

Comment: I thought about approach with private buckets and I think it's the right choice for me from security perspective.... thanks!